# Azure Front Door - troubleshooting unhealty origins

Tags: logging, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

We are testing out Front Door and doing some debugging where Front Door cannot connect to an App Service.

We would like to find some logs telling us something about *why* it cannot connect to the origin (App Service), does this exist?

We did belive the "FrontDoorHealthProbeLog" would give some answers, but there is no info there on what origin that is failing, but some other URLs:

[image]

(*as we use App Services in this scenarios, we would think the ...azurewebsites.net URL would be shown as origin in the logs*)

This really does not make a lot of sense if you have 20 origins and 10 of them not being reachable from Front Door, how can this be used if the URLs are some Azure backbone ones?

Is it possible to dig up some logs on this?

Answer (score 0):

To get logs information in Azure front door you can make use of ***FrontDoorAccessLog*** access log. It will give every information along with originURL, originIP, originName with ErrorInfo:

Create a Diagnostic setting and added Log Analytics:

[image]

When I check access log, I got all the information of front door running successfully with no error like below:

```c
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.CDN" and Category == "FrontDoorAccessLog"
```

```c
// [Azure Front Door Standard/Premium] Request errors by host and path 
// Count number of requests with error responses by host and path. Summarize number of requests by host, path, and status codes >= 400. 
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.CDN" and Category == "FrontDoorAccessLog"
| where toint(httpStatusCode_s) >= 400
| extend ParsedUrl = parseurl(requestUri_s)
| summarize RequestCount = count() by Host = tostring(ParsedUrl.Host), Path = tostring(ParsedUrl.Path), StatusCode = httpStatusCode_s, ResourceId
| order by RequestCount desc
```

[image]

> This really does not make a lot of sense if you have 20 origins and 10 of them not being reachable from Front Door, how can this be used if the URLs are some Azure backbone ones?

As you have 20 origins and only 10 received traffic. And you want to know if the origins are receiving and responding to health probes, so you know whether the origins are healthy. You can use [healthy probe log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-diagnostics?pivots=front-door-standard-premium#health-probe-log)

You can enable diagnostic settings for your Front Door, using this you can export logs in Azure storage like below:

[image]

To know more in detail, check these references.

[Monitor metrics and logs - Azure Front Door | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-diagnostics?pivots=front-door-standard-premium#logs)

[Viewing Azure FrontDoor logs for error responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/673619/viewing-azure-frontdoor-logs-for-error-responses)  by *GitaraniSharma*